# Ensuring I have all DNS records without nameserver access

Tags: domain-name-system

I am migrating a website for a client, and after logging into their domain control panel, I see they are using cloudflare for their DNS records. I don't have access to this, and neither does the client, as they used an agency previously who have not been forthcoming.

Is it a safe bet that if I use a DNS lookup tool, such as this one https://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/, I'll grab a list of all current DNS records, or is there a chance I'll miss some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tools only look for common records. For example, when I put one of my work domains in there, it shows me 8 records, but I have 73.

It's very common to have unguessable subdomains; as an example, AWS uses records like `_7a84f80d4e287dfd3cf4e61ffb54b119.example.com` to verify that you control a domain name.

There's no substitute, unfortunately, for access to the actual DNS records.

Comment: Thanks. I actually added the site to Cloudflare, and it has found a lot more records. I'm thinking that it has found them all in fact: A, TXT, MX SRV etc. The previous tool only found the common records like you say, ie the ones for my exact domain. The cloudflare scan has found stuff like verification records, office 365 records etc. I'm going to make the switch as there is not really any other option. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible since you're doing a CloudFlare --> CloudFlare transfer, that once your ownership of the domain is verified they'd give you that sort of internal access. It might be worth confirming with their support, though.

Comment: Thanks, I will do. I also checked it by adding a domain i own and know all the DNS for to cloudflare. The cloudflare scan found every single record in my DNS, so im pretty confident at this stage. Cheers I'll mark this as solved.